# How to join 2 tables which have the same columns with another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

As mentionned in the title i want to join 2 tables which have the same columns with another table ,Here is the architecture :[DATABASE Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV5lo.png)

Each "transac" table represent a monthly transaction ,actually i have 2 "transac" tables containing the month 09 2017 and 10 2017 transactions ,they are related to the countries and regions of each country.

My request is to calculate the sum of unites of each table "transac_EUR_M09_17" & "transac_EUR_M10_17" while grouping them by country and region in order to know the sales by country and by region on a monthly basis (M09 and M10 2017).

I tried the following request but the sums are very high ,i think it's either a jointure problem or a misconception of the architecture , here is the SQL SERVER request :

```
 SELECT 

    cntry.country,rg.nom_region,SUM(tr09 .unite) as "sum units
    M09 ",SUM(tr10 .unite) as "sum units M10 "   

    FROM

    [Backup].[dbo].[transac_EUR_M09_17] as tr09    
    JOIN
    [Backup].[dbo].[COUNTRY] as cntry    ON tr09.[cod_country] =
    cntry.[cod_country]    JOIN [Backup].[dbo].Region as rg   
    ON rg.[cod_country] = cntry.[cod_country]    JOIN
    [Backup].[dbo].[transac_EUR_M10_17] as tr10    ON tr10.[cod_country] =
    cntry.[cod_country] 

    where tr09 .cod_region = rg.cod_region and tr10 .cod_region = rg.cod_region

    Group BY cntry.country,rg.nom_region    ORDER BY SUM(tr09 .unite)  asc
```

The result :
[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyYRj.png)

As you can see the figures are very high.

I've found a partial solution, it's to extract each table by itself but it's not a relevant solution especially when i'll add a lot of transac tables.

How can i overcome this problem so i can have as much sums extraction from transac tables as i want ?

Comment: Sounds like a great case for normalizing the data into one table.

Comment: I guess you should to learn how to make questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you add a date to the table, then you could keep all data into that one table instead of monthly tables, which is your nightmare currently.

Comment: why do you have two tables exact the same ?

Comment: Echoing the comments to normalize your data, but in the meantime you could do something like UNIONing your individual month tables together and treating those as a single entity which should make aggregation easier.  Something like:

    ;with cte as (
    SELECT 'M0917' as 'Month', * FROM transac_EUR_M09_17
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'M1017', * FROM transac_EUR_M10_17
    )
    select *
    from cte 

From there you should be able to do your JOINs and grouping.

Comment: I can't because each transac table is related to a product table which change monthly